# My wall appears to be leaking. Can I fix it myself?

Tags: water, drywall, walls, leak

It was raining yesterday, and I noticed this wall on the upper floor of our house was leaking. The house is quiet old, built in 1886, but it was "flipped" within the past few years and almost everything on the interior appears to be brand new. The exterior is vinyl.

I peeled off the section of paint that had bubbled up to look underneath at the drywall:

[image: Farther view]

[image: Closer view]

I'm very comfortable putting up/mudding drywall, but I've never done anything to the exterior of the house before and it's on an upper level anyway. Is this likely something I can fix myself from inside, or does it need to be fixed from the outside and/or by a professional?

Comment: No, leaks are not fixed from the inside. Whether it requires a pro is up to you. Perhaps you could revise to address the actual problem, which would require photos or a clear description of the leak area.

Comment: Find the source of the leak first.  Fixing the wall before you fix the leak is pointless and a waste of resources like time and money.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless the source of the leak is a pipe, the issue will be to the exterior of the house. Could be a leak darn near anywhere on the exterior as water will travel, but in this case, I would hazard a guess that the window is leaking or there is a valley that is cracked near that window.

As far as a hiring a professional goes, that is entirely dependent on your level of comfort of getting in that area of the exterior and checking for damaged areas.